# LuaLaTeX : pass a list to lua as macro parameter, but not seen as a table

Tags: luatex, parameters

I try to pass a list to `lua` as `LaTeX` parameter but can not make it interpreted as a table by `lua`.

if `"#1"` I get : `a,b,c,d,e – n 1 –`, table of one entry

if `#1` I get : `n 5 –` ??

Even with `\unexpanded` it's not better ...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{luacode,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\NbRange}{%
        m           % liste des variables
        }{%

    \directlua{
        for i,k in pairs( table.pack( "#1" ) )
        do
        tex.print (i,k,"--")
        end
    }

} % -- Fin NbRange


\begin{document}

\NbRange{a,b,c,d,e}

hello word

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several issues here.

1. `table.pack()` expects a comma-separated list of values, not a string. So the appropriate syntax would be without the quotes, i.e: `table.pack(#1)`
2. Using the mentioned syntax, Lua would receive: `table.pack(a,b,c,d,e)` in your example, but that is not a list of values, but a list of variables. Undefined variables indeed. So you have to quote each individual char when calling `\NbRange` as in `\NbRange("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")` or use lua code to split a string and produce a list of values.
3. The result of `table.pack()` will be a lua table with "a" stored at index 1, "b" at index 2, etc. but also this table will have a field named "n" which will contain the number of elements in that table. This explains why you get `n 5` in your output (`n` is the `i`, `5` is the `k`). The remaining chars do not appear in your output because, as explained above, they are not values, but `nil` variables. Since you don't want to print also that `n` field, you should use `ipairs` instead of `pairs`. `ipairs` only iterates over elements which have a integer key.
4. Finally, if you want to print the index (`i`), you have to convert it to a string. Otherwise the "binary" value of `i` will be printed, so, for example, if `i` is `1`, the result would be the character with code 1 in the current font (equivalent to TeX `\char"1`)

With all these problems fixed the code is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{luacode,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\NbRange}{%
        m           % liste des variables
        }{%

    \directlua{
        for i,k in ipairs( table.pack( #1 ) )
        do
        tex.print (tostring(i),k,"--")
        end
    }

} % -- Fin NbRange


\begin{document}

\NbRange{"a","b","c","d","e"}

hello word

\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much for this long explanaition. In my case the split solution would be the better way. `for arg in string.gmatch("#1", '([^,]+)') do print( arg ) end` works for me. Is it a good solution ?